# Wifi stutters and is slow after switching from XFCE to KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless

My wifi has gotten incredibly slow with lots of what feel like stutters after switching from XFCE to KDE on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I confess that I don't know where to start diagnosing this issue. I've looked through the KDE settings and none of them are obvious red flags that might cause this issue.

Thanks for any guidance and help!